# Page sections JSP/JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, include, jstl

I'm used to work in PHP. There I would make a Page Class with methods for writing menus headers and footers and call those methods from my script. This way was able to easily change the content of the main menu, editing just the Page Class code.

Now I'm trying JSP and JSTL and I can't find any solution for this problem other than include. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: As to alternatives, you could upgrade JSP to its successor Facelets, or to introduce a template engine/framework like Velocity, FreeMarker, Tiles, etc. But what exactly is the problem you're having with `<jsp:include>`?

Comment: I think the nearest solution you would have is a tag library if you want precise control like that, but as BalusC pointed you utilizing something like Facelets or possibly something like SiteMesh might be the best option.

Comment: I can't say that I have a problem per say but I thought that there should be some more elegant solutions. Because java is a object oriented programming language i was hopping that JSP could inherit that in some way.

Comment: Just write Java code in Java classes the usual way? Note that `<jsp:include>` accepts EL expressions like so `<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/${bean.view}.jsp" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that jsp:include is the best way to solve this.